# my java program only preforms actions sequentially

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, for-loop

I have the following code in my program:

```
public static void remove(int studentID)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < students.length; i++)
        {
            if (roster.get(i).getStudentID()==studentID)
            {
                System.out.println("Student with Student ID of: " + studentID + " has been removed!");
                roster.remove(i);
                return;
            }
            else
            {
               System.out.println("Student with Student ID of: " + studentID + " could not be found! No action taken! ");
               return;
            }
        }
    }
```

Everything seems to compile fine, but when I do a roster.remove I can only sequentially delete a ID out of the array list. I have 5 listings in my array, and if I run the remove method from 1 to 5 it works. However if I start at a number say 2, my loop cannot find the ID and fails.

Being relatively new at Java, I know this may be a simple question, I just simply need help. banging my head against the keyboard has produced nothing of value for this problem.

Thank you very much for any help!

Comment: This is probably not the issue but why are you checking `students.length` in your loop but removing from `roster`?

Comment: You are iterating through `students` but looking and deleting in `roster` - is that intended? We really need to know what types these are.

Comment: Why do you have two `return` statements in each part of your `if-else` statement? This means the iteration will break after 1 step.

Comment: avoid deleting inside loop, and iterate using collection or array length to avoid out of bound exception

Answer (score 1):

Remove return from else clause. Its making i++ as dead code. I hope, this is what you are trying to do.

```
public static void remove(int studentID)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < students.length; i++)
    {
        if (roster.get(i).getStudentID()==studentID)
        {
            System.out.println("Student with Student ID of: " + studentID + " has been removed!");
            roster.remove(i);
            return;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Student with Student ID of: " + studentID + " could not be found! No action taken! ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove return statement from your else block.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, I cannot believe I missed the return! Uhg, now I feel like a real noob.

Incase anyone was curious the outcome of my code, I utilized the roster.size() as my count for i. I also removed the entire else statement, and put the "not found" println outside of the for loop, leaving the break within the if statement.

Thank you all for your quick and very helpful responses!